# Can App A communicate with App B on the same phone?

Tags: android, ios

Assume a user has installed two apps, A and B. I want to be able to send a message to app A on the users phone when an action happens on app B.

Can this be done on Android and/or iOS? Are there any built in frameworks on the platforms that allow for this?

Comment: Yes, this can be done in android with Intents, see [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: -1 for lack of research: [ios interprocess communication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/coreoslayer/coreoslayer.html) and [Android inter application  communication](http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/InterAppCommunication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tutorial for Inter-App communication on Android](http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/InterAppCommunication)

Comment: This is great for Android.Here's a good iOS version.  http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/